UE5 cloth + rope simulation
Can anyone suggest how I can simulate with physics, a cloth in UE5 supported by ropes?
My model is made in blender with cylinder profile ropes (7.5mm), and the net is a plane. The model is subdivided into 35mm squares.
I can't find anywhere about how to simulate this on a static mesh/ skeletal mesh.
I'm guessing I need to make this as a skeletal mesh, but I'm not sure what's needed in terms of bones/ physics.
To illustrate, see these examples, in these the blue cloth is surrounded by a thick black rope:


At the minute, all I've managed to find is that maybe Chaos Flesh might be useable for these.
Thanks
